# Using GM xmlhttpRequest instead of an iframe to display pertinent info from an external page

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest, greasekit, fluid-mac-app-engine

I have loaded an https page on Amazon.co.uk and I wish to display use 'GM xmlhttpRequest' to request the price of an item on a linked page.

## What I’ve been doing so far

I [tried to use an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168812/how-can-i-craft-a-greasemonkey-like-script-to-show-a-different-page-in-the-lower) to display the window:

```
var prodLinks = $("td.product_description a:contains('View Amazon Product Page')");
if (prodLinks.length) {
var iframeSrc = prodLinks[0].href;
iframeSrc = iframeSrc.replace (/http:\/\//, "https://")
    $("body").append ('<iframe id="gmIframe" src="' + iframeSrc + '"></iframe>');


$("#gmIframe").css ( {
    "position":     "absolute",
    "bottom":       "1em",
    "left":         "2em",
    "height":       "25%",
    "width":        "84%",
    "z-index":      "17",
    "background":   "#00FF00"
} );
}
```

The problem with this approach is, that whilst it works, the contents of the iFrame is too cluttered, so I cannot see what I need to, at a glance.

## The stuff I want to see

Let us suppose that the linked page is `https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B001AM72BM/`

The relevant HTML snippet from the aforementioned page:

```
<tr id="actualPriceRow">
<td id="actualPriceLabel" class="priceBlockLabelPrice">Price:</td>
<td id="actualPriceContent"><span id="actualPriceValue"><b class="priceLarge">£2.85</b></span>
<span id="actualPriceExtraMessaging">
```

How, exactly, can I use GM xmlhttpRequest to get the page

## Background : I’m using something similar to GreaseMonkey

This is for Greasekit on [Fluid.app](http://fluidapp.com) (which is very old, but I must using it). You probably don’t even need to know that as it’s very similar to Greasekit. So, for the purposes of this question, you can just pretend it is.

## My attempt at answer

I would try:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
method: "GET",
url: "https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B001AM72BM/",
onload : function(response) {
// do something with the result here
document.getElementByClass(‘priceLarge').innerHTML = response.responseText;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to parse the response from GM_`xmlhttpRequest`, and unlike for an iframe, you don't need to rewrite the URL to SSL.

So:

1. Rather than add an iframe, add a node that will contain your price.
2. Grab the product URL as before.
3. Fetch the URL with GM_xmlhttpRequest.
4. Use jQuery to find the `.priceLarge` node.
5. Write the contents of that node to the node created in step 1.

The complete code, with some UI and error handling, looks like this.  I tested it on [your sample page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/stackoverflow-hannah/parse-iframe-so-make-less-cluttered.html) and it works.

```
var prodLinks = $("td.product_description a:contains('View Amazon Product Page')");
if (prodLinks.length) {
    //--- Make a place to put the price.
    $("td.buybox table td.v_prod_box_topleft").append (
        '<p id="gmPriceResult">Fetching...</p>'
    );

    GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
        method:     'GET',
        url:        prodLinks[0].href,
        onload:     getItemPrice,
        onabort:    reportAJAX_Error,
        onerror:    reportAJAX_Error,
        ontimeout:  reportAJAX_Error
    } );
}

function getItemPrice (resp) {
    /*--- Strip <script> tags and unwanted images from response
        BEFORE parsing with jQuery.  Otherwise the scripts will run and the
        images will load -- wasting time and bandwidth and increasing risk
        of complications.
    */
    var respText    = resp.responseText.replace (/<script(?:.|\n|\r)+?<\/script>/gi, "");
    respText        = respText.replace (/<img[^>]+>/gi, "");
    var respDoc     = $(respText);

    //-- Now fetch the price node:
    var priceNode   = respDoc.find (".priceLarge:first");
    if (priceNode.length) {
        $("#gmPriceResult").text (priceNode.text () );
    }
    else {
        $("#gmPriceResult").text ("Price not found!");
    }
}

function reportAJAX_Error (resp) {
    alert ('Error ' + resp.status + '!  "' + resp.statusText + '"');
}
```

Comment: I just get the "Fetching…” message. However, I have not yet studied your annotations; there might be some tweaks I need to make. I just checked the error console and it says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: GM_xmlhttpRequest`

Comment: [Greasekit supports GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://8-p.info/greasekit/changes.html), but that error suggests that Fluid does not.  Contact Fluid.  There may also be a setting you have to make in Fluid options.  Try adding `// @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest` to the script's metadata section.